# table-header-group not supports for scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

In this example when am giving tbody attribute as "display as block" result is expected. But when gave as "display as table-header-group" i can not set the table row (tr) width to respective th. Please help me.

**Snippet:**

```js
 var $table = $('table.scroll'),
   $bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children(),
   colWidth;

 // Adjust the width of thead cells when window resizes
 $(window).resize(function() {
   // Get the tbody columns width array
   colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
     return $(this).width();
   }).get();
   alert("width:" + colWidth);
   // Set the width of thead columns
   $table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i, v) {
     $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
   });
 }).resize(); // Trigger resize handler
```

```css
table.scroll {
  width: 100%;
  /* Optional */
  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
table.scroll tbody {
  display: block;
}
table.scroll thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}
thead tr th {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  /*text-align: left;*/
}
table.scroll tbody {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
tbody {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}
tbody td,
thead th {
  // width: 20%; /* Optional */  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
tbody td:last-child,
thead th:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="scroll">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Head 1</th>
      <th>Head 2</th>
      <th>Head 3</th>
      <th>Head 4</th>
      <th>Head 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not clear what you trying to achieve.

Comment: table.scroll thead {
  display: table-header-group;
} change this to display:block you can see the difference

Comment: Ok so why can't you use that?

Comment: If i using block getting alignment issue in my page. I need to do with table-header-group only. If i change this i need to do CSS changes again for whole page

Comment: You can try `table.scroll tbody { display: table-header-group; }`

Comment: Yes divy. I have tried this also. But the problem is it affecting the scroll when vertically when it's overflow

Comment: There is no other way around to this just using `table-header-group;`. I am afraid to say then you need to change your layout. **Side Note:** Also it's not very much advisable to use `tables` for layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax data table would be the best solution for you. Here is the link you can achieve you want to do. 
[Data table example](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)  and [Scrolling example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/index.html). Find the scrolling examples in 2nd link

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        '50vh',
        scrollCollapse: true,
         paging:         false
     } );
} );
```

Also you can set the scroll functions using pixels if you need. Using this plug in you dont need manipulate the table. It will re arrange the table.